# 'gpg --symmetric' is corrupting my binaries. How do I prevent this?

Tags: unix, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg

When I run:

```
 gpg --batch --yes -o test_bin.jpg.aes.gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-file=pass.txt  test_bin.jpg
```

and then decrypt with:

```
 gpg --batch --yes -o test_bin.aes.out.jpg  --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-file=pass.txt  test_bin.jpg.aes.gpg
```

I get corrupted data.

Is there another version of the command that I could use instead?